# Get Taxonomy Term by Guid in Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, taxonomy

I have searched the interwebs forever but can't seem to find a simple example of how to get a taxonomy term by guid in Powershell using the CSOM.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample demo by CSOM PowerShell.

```
$url="http://sp"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll"

$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)

$MMS = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession]::GetTaxonomySession($clientcontext)
$clientContext.Load($MMS)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

$guid = New-Object System.Guid("28cd5378-92f3-48bc-aa39-5e27ea475211");
$term=$MMS.GetTerm($guid)
$clientContext.Load($term)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
Write-Host $term.Name
```

Answer (score 2):

We do have method on TermSet object to getTerm based on GUID.

TermSet.GetTerm(Guid) Method - Gets a Term from the current TermSet based on its ID.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.termset.getterm

Below code snippet from ref link -https://seyedketabchi.wordpress.com/2011/03/27/accessing-taxonomies-from-powershell/

```
$url = "http://MySP2010/sites/CoolSites/"
$web = Get-SPWeb $url
$taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $web.Site
$termStore = $taxonomySession.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"];
foreach($item in $termStore.Groups){
if($item.Name -eq "Marketing")
{
$group = $item
}
}
Write-Host "---->: " $group.Name

$termset = $group.TermSets["Marketing Initiative"];
$guid = New-Object System.Guid("c1353ee2-b2b2-4fc9-90a2-3b912390b6ac");
$term = $termset.GetTerm($guid);


Write-Host $term.Name;

}
```